# Change Port from 8080 to 80 to see JBoss/Wildfly Java app on domain name, not IP Address

Tags: dns, jboss, port, wildfly

I have a Java application that uses Wildfly 16, on dedicated Linux server, running WHM CentOS 6.10.  The application works on the IP Adresss port 8080.

The Apache 2.4 is installed and running.  I was told Apache uses port 80 which the domain name resides on.  I can see from the domain URL the boilerplate index.html page which is under public_html but do not the WildFly index page.
The IP address port 8080 does show the WildFly index page. Which needs to be shown using the domain name.

I tried the following:

`./bin/standalone.sh -Djboss.http.port=80`

ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.undertow.listener.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.undertow.listener.default: Address already in use /127.0.0.1:80

Within the standalone.xml I changed the following:
`<socket-binding name="http" port="80"/>`

Unfortunately I do not know a way to post all of the error but I am able to submit the following:
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]  - failure description: "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => "org.wildfly.undertow.listener.default"

INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service org.wildfly.undertow.listener.default: WFLYUT0082: Could not start 'default' listener.

Tried again in standalone.xml by changing the following:
`<socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:80}"/>`

ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]  WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed -address:

- failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.undertow.listener.default" => "WFLYUT0082: Could not start 'default' listener.
  Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied"

WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service org.wildfly.undertow.listener.default: WFLYUT0082: Could not start 'default' listener.
WFLYCTL0448: 2 additional services are down due to their dependencies being missing or failed

Lastly, in case this help, this standalone.xml also includes the following:

```
<interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
 </interfaces>
```

Please help to switch the application from IP Address, port 8080 to show in the domain URL.  Perhaps I need to forward or point domain to the JBOSS home directory.  Not sure or how.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an "Address already in use error" because Apache httpd is already bound to port 80. Therefore, you can't bind your WildFly Java app to port 80 and your Java app will not start because of this. You'll need to configure/integrate your Apache Web Server with WildFly. Something like Apache serves static content while WildFly is its application server. You'll have something like this in your `httpd.conf`:

```
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel info
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
```

then you'll have something like this in your `vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot "/dir/dir"
    
    ... snipped ...

    JkMount /* jboss
</VirtualHost>
```

then something like this in `workers.properties`:

```
worker.list = jboss

worker.jboss.type=ajp13
worker.jboss.host=localhost
worker.jboss.port=8009
```

then in `standalone.xml`:

```
<socket-binding-group ... snipped ... >
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}" />
    ... snipped ...
</socket-binding-group>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am a little confused by your answer.  Do I need to add to my httpd.conf? Also I cannot locate a vhost.conf but I do have the <VirtualHost info in my httpd.conf file.   I cannot locate the workers.properties file.  Does that need to be created?  In the standalone.xml I do have a socket-binding ajb.  Should any modifications be made to the standalone.xml file?

Comment: My answer is meant to point you in the direction of integrating Apache Web Server with WildFly/JBoss. Have you googled that? The idea is you don't need to change the WildFly port. Yes, `VirtualHost` can be inside `httpd.conf`. Please read httpd manual and WildFly manual regarding `ajp` connection. Try googling "apache as a front end to wildfly using mod_jk".

Comment: I left out an important piece earlier.  The site used to worked as intended before the application server box was rebooted.  I was not aware of how Wildfly or Apache worked before but did a `httpd -M` and `rpm –qa | grep mod_proxy` to see the enabled apache module on the server is mod_proxy.  The `httpd.conf` directs me to the administrator include file `pre_virtualhost_global.conf`.  Unfortunately none of my updates in that file performed any change good or bad, even though I did a stop/start on httpd and wildfly.

Comment: Yes, that is another way of integrating Apache with WildFly/JBoss. Instead of searching for how to configure `mod_jk`, search for `mod_proxy`. With `mod_proxy`, I'm guessing you are using Apache as a load balancer.

Comment: Please see UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

Using Apache as a Reverse Proxy to Wildfly through mod_proxy with CentOS.

1. Verify the config file (httpd.conf) Apache uses

   httpd - V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE
2. Verify the modules are enabled, either in `httpd.conf` or in modules `includes` files

   LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
   LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
3. Since the `httpd.conf` file warned against updates in file due to new Apache upgrades or regeneration of config file, to instead use the config `include` files.  In this case the `includes/post_virtualhost_global.conf` (not `pre_virtualhost_global.conf`).
4. Add the following to `includes/post_virtualhost_global.conf`

   ProxyPreserveHost On
   Proxypass / http://localhost:8080/
   ProxypassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
5. Restart Apache service

   service httpd stop

   service httpd start